# Docusign how to add carbon copy recipients in TemplateRole

Tags: docusignapi

is it possible to add carbon copy recipient to TemplateRole? ,

for example if we create a envelope from a document we will provide "signer" and "carbonCopies" , but when we create an envelope from a template how can i differentiate between signer and carbonCopies recipients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is C# Code (if you need other lang - go to https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote)

```
TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
    signer1.Email = signerEmail;
    signer1.Name =  signerName;
    signer1.RoleName = "signer";

    TemplateRole cc1 = new TemplateRole();
    cc1.Email = ccEmail;
    cc1.Name = ccName;
    cc1.RoleName = "cc";
```

Comment: thanks for the info , but how to differentiate between signer and cc , if i provide RoleName as "cc" then it will be given "receive a copy" in docusign embedded  iframe

Comment: There's no embedded iframe for cc, this is a person that receives a copy, which is via email only. 
Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but the code above would help you create an envelope from a template with both types of recipients.